# Spring config server always connecting to default instead of actual url configured

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have a springboot application which connects to config server to fetch the application properties.
Application properties are stored in azure blob.
I have yaml files which are used to deploy the application to kubernetes cluster.
i am using below cloud dependencies to implement this config client functionality.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
 </dependency>  
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

configmap yaml file looks like this

```
      kind: ConfigMap
        apiVersion: v1
      metadata:
        name: test-app-v1
      namespace: testnamespace
      labels:
      app: test-app
      version: v1
    data:
      bootstrap.yaml: |
      spring:
      application:
      name: test-app
      profiles:
      active: dev
      cloud:
      config:
      uri: http://1.1.1.1/v1/configs
      # the version of config it is going to look
      label: v1
      fail-fast: true
      retry:
        max-attempts: 3
```

**But when application is started what  is observed is it always tries to connect to default config url which is localhost:8888 and not http://1.1.1.1 which is config server url configured in yaml**

Part of application yaml looks like this which includes which config map to refer

```
volumes:
    - name: log-volume
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        name: test-app-v1
        items:
          - key: bootstrap.yaml
            path: bootstrap.yaml
            mode: 0755
```

I follow same approach in many other applications and have no issues with them.
Any pointers to the problem will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap? You can try removing spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap to see if it can fix the problem.